# How can i create FaceBook and Gmail type web based chat in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, facebook

How can i create FaceBook and Gmail type web based chat in ASP.Net?

i think its called one to one chat.

i have try with XMPP but need base example code

i already install open fire. can anyone have sample code for this type

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is a good option to build a chat application.

Comment: is it free? is it support asp.net ?

Comment: No @DhavalGandhi , they give you a library. You have to write the code.

Comment: is it related to XMPP or for this no need to XMPP ?

Comment: Read. Everything you want to know is here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki. This link is there on the main site itself